# Pentaho kettle: How to prevent db transformation step from always executing?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a transformation that has a switch case which can either run a database retrieval transformation or do nothing based on the switch case value.

The problem is that the database transformation seems to get executed always no matter what the result of the switch case is. The database name is parametrized and the switch case tries to make sure that non existing database names are ignored and not queries (as this causes an error). But now the database transformation runs every time and causes an error.

So the question is: Is there a way to prevent the a database transformation from automatically executing? I've tried adding a blocking step before it but with no results.

Comment: Which step are you using to execute the "database transformation"? 'Execute SQL script'? 'Execute row SQL script'?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do this before and hit the exact same problem. It's fundamentally to how PDI works, if your step wont initialize then nothing will run - there is no solution to this.  In fact, I even have a jira about this, but it doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

However perhaps you're doing this about face. Why do you have conditional connections? IF you could explain the use case then perhaps we can propose a better solution.